# GeoServer multiple style directories

Tags: geoserver

I'm working on a geoserver instance. A style directory can be found in two places:

- A) /styles
- B) /data/workspaces/default/styles

Both contain the same set of styles except the one in the root contains the generic line, point, etc. styles.

My guess is the latter exists for portability reasons? My questions are:

- which one is used? Or how does Geoserver decide which style is picked if styles are identical in both directories?
- To tidy things up, in which folder should I remove styles to only have one copy. For example Keep generic in A) and the others in B) or only use A) and delete the style folder in workspaces  (B) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my local system I have no `workspaces/default` directory so that is probably the copy, but I don't use any workspace based styles so it may get created if you do that.

As for which one is used that depends - in general GeoServer will use the ones in the `/styles` directory **unless** you are referring to a style in a workspace in which case it will use the ones in `/workspace/name/styles` and can only be used on layers that are in that workspace. It usually assumes that you are accessing the [virtual service for that workspace](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/virtual-services.html).

Comment: thanks, @Ian Turton where I'm puzzled is: the layer.xml is referencing the style without any path definition f.e. https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/data/release/workspaces/sf/sf/roads/layer.xml#L7 my question is do you know if there is some kind of hierarchy like: first search in the workspace based /styles dir (which is closest) and if the file is not there search in the roots /style dir. In other words, what I do not understand yet is how geoserver deals with the multiple style directories. (as this would answer where I keep my styles)

Comment: It depends do you want to use the style with layers in more than one workspace - then use the global directory, or do you want to limit access to a specific workspace and so need to have layers and styles in that workspace.

Comment: Thanks, Ian I think I got it. This sounds as I should definitely delete a style that lives in both directories (with same id)